# Devise routes not showing on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

I am using Devise with my rails app. It works great locally. I have pushed everything to Heroku but when I run heroku rake routes the Devise routes don't show up. I just get:

```
    home_index GET    /home/index(.:format)     home#index
 deals_new GET    /deals/new(.:format)      deals#new
 deals_all GET    /deals/all(.:format)      deals#all
     deals GET    /deals(.:format)          deals#index
           POST   /deals(.:format)          deals#create
  new_deal GET    /deals/new(.:format)      deals#new
 edit_deal GET    /deals/:id/edit(.:format) deals#edit
      deal GET    /deals/:id(.:format)      deals#show
           PUT    /deals/:id(.:format)      deals#update
           DELETE /deals/:id(.:format)      deals#destroy
      root        /                         home#index
```

UPDATE:

I have got it mostly working. The sign_up route is still missing though:

```
          home_index GET    /home/index(.:format)         home#index
           deals_new GET    /deals/new(.:format)          deals#new
           deals_all GET    /deals/all(.:format)          deals#all
               deals GET    /deals(.:format)              deals#index
                     POST   /deals(.:format)              deals#create
            new_deal GET    /deals/new(.:format)          deals#new
           edit_deal GET    /deals/:id/edit(.:format)     deals#edit
                deal GET    /deals/:id(.:format)          deals#show
                     PUT    /deals/:id(.:format)          deals#update
                     DELETE /deals/:id(.:format)          deals#destroy
    new_user_session GET    /user/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
        user_session POST   /user/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session DELETE /user/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
       user_password POST   /user/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
   new_user_password GET    /user/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
  edit_user_password GET    /user/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                     PUT    /user/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                root        /                             home#index
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved this. In my user.rb model there was an:

```
 if Rails.env.production?
```

Devise had several options set here. In the local environment :registerable was set. It was missing in the production environment. That's why the routes were showing locally and not in production.

Comment: I had the EXACT same issue. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Actually routes should have got shown. there is nothing which heroku does extra.. 
Please check on the following-

1. You have latest code deployed on heroku

   git push heroku master
2. Restart heroku server

   heroku restart --app [your app name]

Comment: I tried both of those but the devise routes still aren't showing up. Everything works fine locally just not on the server.

Comment: i am dammn sure that devise gem is not getting loaded on heroku .. you may have missed out checkin of Gemfile/ Gemfile.lock

Comment: I just checked and Gemfile and Gemfile.lock have been committed.

Comment: While doing git push heroku master.. and while slug compilation have you observed that devise gem is getting installed?

Comment: If you see my update, I've nearly got it working. The sign_up route is still missing though.

Comment: @kmcgrady how it can be 'nearly'.. it will be either work or wil not work? :P

Comment: It is showing most of the devise routes now but sign_up is still missing.

Comment: @kmcgrady how other devise routes started showing up suddenly?

Comment: I was missing devise_for :users in my routes.rb

Comment: @kmcgrady dude that was so stupid mistake ..then how it was working on your dev machine :)

Comment: I've been working on this problem for a few days so accidentally took it out while trying different things. I re-ran the tests and I am seeing all the routes locally. On Heroku I'm still missing the sign_up routes.